# Crystal Reports - make single Column values from data source as row

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working with CR 2014. My requirement is to put the values of a single column across 4 rows.
That is, below is my table values.

---

**Column 1** **Column2**

val1                   100 
val2                     200
val3                     300
val4                     400
val5                     500

I need to put each values of **Column2** as follows in report

title1        title2      title3      title4      title5
             100                200              300                400 
             
            500         ...       ...         ... 
Is it possible to achieve this through crystal reports? I do not want to just design it using multiple columns from section expert. I want to map the data of each column to the cell value in crystal report.

Comment: If i understand your requirement correctly, would be easier creating a sql view that uses PIVOT function and then using the view in the report.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using `If` conditions....

Create a formula like below:

```
if Column 1='Val1'
then Column 2
```

Place the formula in report and like this create formulas for all values and place one by one.